# cannot convert type dto to type Ienumerable

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an asp.net core web.api and need to return DTO object from Ienumerable method. I am getting error in the controller get method saying cannot convert DTO to type Ienumerable

```
 namespace Products.DTO
{
    public class Products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public DateTime Available { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

}

namespace Products.API.Controllers
{
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
        {

            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult<IEnumerable<DTO.Products>> GetProducts()
            {
                return new DTO.Products  
                {
                    Id = 1, Name = "Cricket bat", Available = DateTime.Now, Code = "AC122333", Price = 1223.23M
                };
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
return new DTO.Products[]{  
    DTO.Products { Id = 1, Name = "Cricket bat", Available = DateTime.Now, Code = "AC122333", Price = 1223.23M }
};
```